# Datetime difference in seconds in a 100K+ rows Dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, data-science

Im really new to Python and Datascience.

I have a Dataset with 100K+ rows, and like 30 columns(Two datetime, 27 integers and 1 string). 
I wanna create a 31th column by computing difference between my two datetimes columns and get the result in seconds. Also, i wanna make "-5000" as the minimum diffrence between my two dates.

So to make it easy, lets just focus only on the two Datetime columns.

The goal is to go from this:

```
        first_datetime        second_datetime
0  2019-03-13 04:35:30  2019-03-13 05:35:30
1  2019-03-13 05:35:30  2019-03-13 06:35:30
2  2019-03-13 05:35:30  2019-03-14 06:35:30
```

To This :

```
   diff       first_datetime        second_datetime
0 -3600    2019-03-13 04:35:30  2019-03-13 05:35:30
1   -10    2019-03-13 05:35:30  2019-03-13 05:35:40
2 -5000    2019-03-13 05:35:30  2019-03-14 05:35:40
```

I've been told that the .apply function is the fastest, so i used it to make this function:

```
def calc_diff(row):
    diff=int((row['first_datetime']-row['second_datetime']).total_seconds())
    if diff<-5000:
         return -5000
    else:
         return diff
```

And im using it with the .apply function :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'first_datetime': "2019-03-13 04:35:30", 'second_datetime': "2019-03-13 05:35:30"},{'first_datetime': "2019-03-13 05:35:30", 'second_datetime': "2019-03-13 05:35:40"}])

df['diff']=df.apply(calc_diff, axis=1)
```

The problem is that im getting a Memory Error, im i doing something wrong ? What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you add the full traceback of the error?

Comment: Because your code works for me, if you fix the column name typo. You have `'secod_datime'` in the dataframe, and `'second_datetime'` in the `calc_diff`. So maybe is just a typo.

Comment: @Valentino the typo is just to illustrate it, i cant really make it "Easily understandable" with the actual dataset inputs

Comment: Column names must match. If they don't match, you get an error. As I said, if you fix the typo, your code works and you get the expected result. So what is the real quesiton?

Comment: @Valentino the real question is : How to achieve such thing when working with a large dataset containing 100K+ or 1M rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
df["diff"]= (df["first_datetime"]-df["second_datetime"]).dt.seconds.clip(lower=-5000)
```

**Edit:**
About the difference beetwen dt.seconds and dt.total_seconds():

```
(pd.Timestamp("2019-10-13 00:00:50")-pd.Timestamp("2019-10-10 00:00:00")).seconds                                    
Out: 50

(pd.Timestamp("2019-10-13 00:00:50")-pd.Timestamp("2019-10-10 00:00:00")).total_seconds()                            
Out: 259250.0
```

Comment: Im having this error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'seconds'`, and before returning the result of the difference, i wanna check if it is smaller than -5000, and if it is, i want to set it to -5000 (in order to have -5000 as the minimum), how can i achieve this using your solution?

Comment: .dt.total_seconds()?

Comment: @QuangHoang , i had already tried with `.total_seconds()` before posting my comment but it didn't work. `.dt.total_seconds()` seems to work, may i ask whats the difference between them?

Comment: For pandas time Series, you need `dt` access. For Pandas time Index, you don’t need it.

Comment: @le fragan Maybe you need total_seconds because dt.seconds  >= 0 and less than 1 day!

Comment: @kantal Yes, i used total_seconds, Thank you Quang Hoang